# Python selenium can't find the search box in ebay

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ebay-api

I am trying to get python selenium to click on the description box for eBay selling but it can't find it. I have tried to switch to the frame but it can't find them either. This is the code I have now.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('v4-183txtEdit_st')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="v4-183txtEdit_st_wr"]/div[2]').click()
```

[image]
This is an image of the description box I am trying to get selenium to click on.

This is it but with inspect element.
[image]

Comment: What element are you trying to locate the search box or description(what?) box?

Comment: Description box.

Comment: What is it? Can you clarify?

Comment: This is a link to the image of the description box https://prnt.sc/1qij9db

Comment: I see nothing there

Comment: This is a better image. https://prnt.sc/1qijich It has the code of it.on the side

Comment: Where on eBay do you see such element?

Comment: It is where you want to sell an item

Comment: Well, this is not so clear. You have to mention this exactly in your question. The entire flow, what to do in order to get there

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already in another frame so I had to exit. This is the code I used.

```
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```